# Given a 'Location' model, which has_many 'tags' (Tag), find all locations which own associated (tag) records with a certain tag column value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, join, include, has-and-belongs-to-many

So I'm trying to find all Locations which have Tags with the name "school". Location has_many Tags and Tag has_many Locations via a join table accessed via the :through model method

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :location_tags
  has_many :locations, :through => :location_tags
end

class LocationTag < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :location
  belongs_to :tag
end

class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :location_tags
  has_many :locations, :through => :location_tags
end
```

So those are my models. I know the solution will involve `includes`, `joins` or something along those lines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it.

```
Location.where(query_stuff).includes(:tags).where(:tags => { :name => "school" })
```

Answer (score 1):

`Tag.where(:name => 'school').locations`

Comment: hmmm...this is a solution. I'd like to learn how to do it from the other side though, for example if I had a selected set of locations already and wanted to find the ones within that set which owned tags of the "school" type